# Best way to stock tokens with WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, token, wso2-esb

I am working on some systems that needs to use Access and Refresh tokens.
In my process now, I save tokens in registry, and I update them when they need to be updated. But sometimes, I get an error because one of my process tries to retrieve a token, but this token has been changed just before (like a lock in the registry).

What is the best way to store, update and retrieve that kind of informations ?

I tried to use a class mediator which stores properties in a Hashmap, but WSO2 always create a new instance of my custom class, so a new instance of my hashmap.

Any idea ? Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

The usual practice to store the token is in the registry. This is used in the connector implementation [1] in the ESB server. Could you elaborate more on the issue? What is the ESB server version? What is the error stack trace? Have you used a similar implementation as in [1]?

Further to answer your question regarding the class mediator, you can use a static variable in the class mediator to share the token among the objects created. But then again, static variables are not thread-safe.

[1]-https://github.com/wso2-extensions/esb-connector-gmail/blob/master/src/main/resources/config/getAccessTokenFromRefreshToken.xml

Comment: I use 6.6.0. For [1], I used the same way to store and retrieve token from registry. But, because we do a lot of requests (400 imports, 5 requests each in a small time, async), registry database lock itself when it changes its value.

Comment: Then you can implement a class mediator with a static variable to store the token and use a synchronized block for its access. You may have to perform a load test and check if there is a performance impact prior to adding it to a production environment.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the registry for reading / storing data, and here is some issue..
When you read using property mediator, for example token - he is also cached for default 15sec. So after read, revoke new one, and store back - you will still get from property mediator the "old" one. This can be bypassed, using script mediator and store registry entry using code, and setting the CachableDurationto 0.

I described this reading storing from registry in my [blog](https://devintegra.com/how-to-read-modify-write-to-wso2-enterprise-integrator-registry), check out especially the *Known downside* paragraph.